# Gender randomization in clinical studies

Tags: clinical-trials, random-allocation

Hi i'm sorry if this has been asked before but I'm confused about the boundaries of gender randomization/distribution in a clinical study.

I have an example study of 430 participants with multiple variables (>20), one of which is gender with the men being only 15% of the entire dataset. Would it be OK to make a model for all participants or do I have to only consider the women in this case?

Thanks

Comment: Clinical trial statisticians spend decades studying questions like this, so expect to do a lot of reading.  Start with the ANCOVA chapter in [BBR](https://hbiostat.org/bbr) then get Stephen Senn's _Statistical Issues in Drug Development_, 3rd edition.  Briefly, adjustment covariates are to be completely pre-specified in a randomized trial, and the top criterion for selection is the current state of knowledge of how important a baseline variable is in predicting the outcome being studied (no after-the-fact stepwise variable selection allowed).